# Error in declaring a function pointer with gcc 4.5.2 on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: c, gcc

```
int (*foo)(epoll_event e, void *data);
```

If I name the file with cc extension, this gets accepted. With .c extension this

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘e’
```

I have googled and declaration seems to be valid for C. Can anyone please provide input on how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the definition of epoll_event ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing `epoll_event` is not a type name, it's a structure tag name.

In this case you need to add `struct`:

```
  int (*foo)(struct epoll_event e, void *data);
```

This [page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_ctl) suggests so:

```
struct epoll_event {
    uint32_t     events;      /* Epoll events */
    epoll_data_t data;        /* User data variable */
};
```